# How to know encoding of this file?

Tags: string, reverse-engineering, decoding

I thought this is **base64 encoding** so i try to decode it in that way but it seems this is not base64 encoding. I want to decode this.

> O7hrHYO5UUFHFPVILQPc6A==:hEnb3PVrxgHbEL1VT+cu8ic4ocIOfoaWkJ2b2MCrVy4=:jXB0R2OctZ6i1K3s2DlLNS5D/PSdhzKM7GX7gVh6AvXbWrA5i/4j3maFlgk1X2BpmOXYoZab2hAJS4lCBtWi6WnE3zDLhBvWJWFyAN93fIvS66PXJiINmaEhKi8mBIjc

I am learning about reverse eng. and i got this file. This is simple quiz app. (android) in database file it has question with above encoding string. I put here first one. There are many more questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

The colon character `:` cannot appear in base64 output, and also `=` can only appear at the end of base64 output, so this string seems to be composed of 3 parts, each individually encoded in base64:

```
O7hrHYO5UUFHFPVILQPc6A==
hEnb3PVrxgHbEL1VT+cu8ic4ocIOfoaWkJ2b2MCrVy4=
jXB0R2OctZ6i1K3s2DlLNS5D/PSdhzKM7GX7gVh6AvXbWrA5i/4j3maFlgk1X2BpmOXYoZab2hAJS4lCBtWi6WnE3zDLhBvWJWFyAN93fIvS66PXJiINmaEhKi8mBIjc
```

These don't decode to anything meaningful in base64, so my guess is some encryption scheme has been applied. After decoding, the lengths of these are all multiple of 16 bytes, which hints at a block cipher with blocks of 16 bytes (128 bits).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think then we can not decode this without key. ?

Comment: You need to find out more about the encryption scheme, it's unlikely to be complicated. The key might be hard coded in the source code of the app.